Using a str variable as a key for a map always returns null
I am trying to use a Map without success.
I have whittled it down to a bare-bones case:
I create a Map with four entries:
("fruit", 25)
("veg", 30)
("baked", 35)
("flower", 40)

I create a variable: str: String for my key. I then assign a value to the variable: var str = "fruit"
I try doing v = myMap[str], and I get null. Same result with myMap.get(str).
If I try v = myMap["fruit"], I get 25. If I try v = myMap.get("fruit"), I also get 25.
Any ideas? The actual app has 2500 (key, value) pairs so I really need this to work with a variable holding the key.

Apparently, your str is not really holding the value "fruit". Please provide a minimal reproducible example. It's hard to guess what could be wrong if you didn't provide any code.

I recommend to you debug and put a breakpoint here
v = myMap[str]

And then check the value of str variable, if it is not "fruit" you found your problem
